# Having trouble understanding front-to-backend communication

Tags: node.js, express, http, request

I'm learning how to connect frontend to backend with Node but I'm having trouble understanding. I have the following code

backend.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');


const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>hello, world.</h1>');
})

app.get('/testGet', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Golden rubbers in these denim pockets');
})

app.use(cors);

app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`) })
```

index.js

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('http://localhost:8080/testGet').then(res => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

The thing I am having trouble understanding is why I have to specify the port and localhost as the hostname in the GET request. I know the express server is running on that port, but I've seen people do the same thing without specifying those things, for example:

```
axios.get('/testGet').then(res => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

Was I misunderstanding something in the tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

When you do an Ajax requests without specifying the domain the **browser** will use the current site domain.

So if you input in the browser `http://localhost:8080` and call '/testGet' the request will be sent to `http://localhost:8080/testGet`. Note that that port is a part of the `domain` (different port is a different domain) and if no port is supplied the port will default to port `80`

You can test using the browser dev-tools and look at the network traffic.

Comment: so in a production environment I would have to specify the port in my request since the frontend would be on port 80 so I couldn't use port 80 for the backend? For example if on my frontend I had a button that when clicked would make a request to the backend, the request would be to a domain like: `http://example.com:3000/testGet`?

Comment: In production, your environment needs to be exposed on port `80`. You can use `reverse proxy` in order to expose a single port but have the ability to route request to the web-server or API server (see: https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-plus-as-an-api-gateway-part-1/)